# Comparando Integer e int usando "== " y ".equals()"

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo el OCA Java SE 8 Programmer I Certification Guide.Cuando habla de los wrappers dice que los numericos almacenan valores de -128 a 127(Long,Integer,Short y Byte)y Character de 0 a 127.Se dice que cuando se usa el valueOf se devuelve una referencia del valor pedido si es que esta dentro de ese rango y sino crea un nuevo objeto y devuelve su referencia.
En esta prueba que hice,la clase wrapper almacena un valor de 200(fuera del rango ) y le asigne a una variable primitiva el mismo valor.

```
 Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(200);    
    int a=200;
    System.out.println(i3==a);//devuelve true
```

en cambio si hago esto:

```
        Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(200);  
    Integer i4 = Integer.valueOf(200);
   System.out.println(i3==i4);//devuelve false
```

Cuando se comparan Wrappers con primitivos solo se tiene en cuenta el valor?Es decir,funciona como una especie de equals?Como funciona el mecanismo de comparacion con "==" entre variables primitivas y wrappers,si este signo de comparacion es encargado de comparar referencias a objetos y no referencias a valores como lo hace el ".equals()"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intentaré explicar ambos casos lo mejor que pueda, pero no se me da excesivamente bien el lenguaje técnico.

```
Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(200);    
int a=200;
System.out.println(i3==a);//devuelve true
```

Efectivamente, un Integer es un objeto de clase Integer, los primitivos en java no son clases, así que es imposible comparar si ambos objetos son el mismo. Lo que la VM hace en este caso es [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) (Puedes leer más acerca de esto en el enlace) del Integer, obtener el valor primitivo que representa y comparar si son iguales.

En este segundo caso:

```
Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(200);  
Integer i4 = Integer.valueOf(200);
System.out.println(i3==i4);//devuelve false
```

estás comparando dos objetos, que si bien tienen el mismo valor, han sido creados por separado por lo cual representan a dos objetos diferentes cada uno con su referencia.
El hecho de que sean wrappers no implica gran cosa (excepto para el unboxing) a la hora de compararlos con `==`, ya que para el `==` siempre que sean dos objetos, va a mirar únicamente sus referencias y, si son diferentes, son diferentes.

En resumen, siempre se que comparen un objeto (Integer, Float, Boolean...) y un primitivo la VM hace unboxing del objeto y compara ambos primitivos.

Comment: Perfectamente explicado amigo,sospechaba que comparaba solo el valor cuando era un Wrapper y un primitivo pero no sabia de que manera.Gracias

Comment: @SantiSalinas Si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda aceptarla.

Comment: Para el rango de -128 a 127 la JVM no realiza el unboxing, obtiene los valores de una "cached pool" y por lo tanto la comparación con el operador `==` funciona, aunque es recomendable siempre usar `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma alternativa si te sale error, o no te parece una forma común de hacerlo, podrías probar convertir a String los datos y compararlos con la función equals.